# Admin permissions wiped out after git branching

Tags: users, version-control

I've encountered a strange issue whereby creating a new git branch on a Drupal 7 site and switching to it causes admin users' permissions to seemingly disappear. After performing the git branch, all admin users (who normally have near full access) see the admin toolbar but only have the ability to add content. All other links are missing.

I have tried visiting admin pages directly and that yields access denied. I have tried rebuilding permissions and clearing cache as well. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: No. What is the output of `git status` after you branched?

Comment: What differs between the original branch and the new branch?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that rows strangely went missing from the `roles` table (in particular admin roles) upon creating a new git branch. I have not tracked down *why* this happens, but I suspect that something in either one of the features or custom modules is causing this to happen.